# How can I pass an argument to a command defined and called in a .cls file using another command called in a .tex and defined in the previous .cls?

Tags: macros, cv, arguments

I am building a résumé on which I would like to list the languages I speak and my level in each one of them. To present the levels, I wish to use skill dots. I want to obtain a structure similar to the one shown in the image below

[image]

To do so, I defined a new command named `\cvlanguages` on a .cls file :

```
\newcommand{\cvlanguages}[2]{\renewcommand{\cvlanguages}{#1 \grade{#2}}}
```

Later on the .cls code, in order to print the "Languages" section on the résumé, I use the following:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\cvlanguages}{}}{}{
    \profilesection{LANGUAGES}
    {\cvlanguages}
}
```

`\profilesection` is defined elsewhere and is not important here.

The `\grade` command is also on the .cls file and is given by:

```
\newcommand{\grade}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (1em-.4em,-.35em) rectangle (5em +.5em ,1em);
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{
            \path[{fill=backColor}] (\x em,0) circle (.35em);
        }
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (1em-.4em,-.35em) rectangle (#1 em +.5em ,1em);
            \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{
            \path[{fill=frontColor}] (\x em,0) circle (.35em);
            }
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

On the .tex file, I use the following line to call the `\cvlanguages` command:

```
\cvlanguages{Portuguese}{5}
```

This procedure causes a fatal error and I have no idea why. The command `\grade` works perfectly when it is outside the `\renewcommand` nested in the `\newcommand`.

I have considered an alternative solution using something like this instead:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\cvlanguages}{}}{}{
    \profilesection{LANGUAGES}
    {\fontsize{0.36cm}{0.432cm} \selectfont \cvlanguages{#1} \grade{\cvlanguages{#2}}}
}
```

but I have no idea how to make this work, as specifying which argument to print using "#" doesn't seem to work inside this `\ifthenelse` environment.

I am new to this level of LaTex and have spent a while trying to figure this out, with no success. I would appreciate any help on how to work around this problem.

Comment: `\ifthenelse` doesn't care about `#1`, `#2`, etc. These, when used in the replacement text of a macro,  are replaced by the corresponding arguments when said macro is expanded. IMHO, you should provide *one file* (code block) containing your code, as short as possible. Something self-contained. You can use the `filecontents` (or `filecontents*`) environment if you really need several files. Otherwise, it is just complicated and fuzzy for us to guess how each part is used and what fails in which way.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a full example document, but only from your code snippets my best guess is that at some point `\cvlanguages` is defined to call itself when expanded, thus bringing the compiler into an infinite loop. Also, what's the purpose of the test `\equal{\cvlanguages}{}}`? Given either of your definitions for `\cvlanguages`, this command can never produce an empty token list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially `\cvlanguages` is defined to consume two non delimited macro arguments and to redefine itself.
This redefining can happen **exactly once**.
When this redefining happens, then `\cvlanguages` is redefined not to consume any macro argument and to expand to something like the phrase "`Portugese \grade{5}`" and thus is not "redefinable" any more.

This means:

1. You can use `\cvlanguages` exactly once with two non delimited macro arguments for setting one language.
   After that you can use `\cvlanguages` without macro arguments for listing that one language and the skill-dots.
2. If you did not use `\cvlanguages` exactly once with two non delimited macro arguments for setting one language, then `\cvlanguages` is still defined to consume two non delimited macro arguments. This circumstance may/will disturb the comparison of `\cvlanguages`'s expansion to emptiness within the `\ifthenelse`-construct.

I suggest using the `\@starttoc`-mechanism:

In the example below the macro `\cvlanguages` is used for adding a language and a grade to the list of cvlanguages and the macro `\listofcvlanguages` is used for delivering the list of cvlanguages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% As you didn't provide definitions for these, I invented something on my own:
\definecolor{frontColor}{named}{black}
\definecolor{backColor}{named}{lightgray}
\newcommand\profilesection[1]{%
  \noindent\textsf{\textbf{#1}}\\\null\hrulefill\null\\%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand{\grade}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
      \clip (1em-.4em,-.35em) rectangle (5em +.5em ,1em);%
      \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{%
          \path[{fill=backColor}] (\x em,0) circle (.35em);%
      }%
      \begin{scope}%
          \clip (1em-.4em,-.35em) rectangle (#1 em +.5em ,1em);%
          \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{%
          \path[{fill=frontColor}] (\x em,0) circle (.35em);%
          }%
      \end{scope}%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\newcommand\cvlanguagesectionheading{%
  \ifnum\cvlanguagecountmacro<1 \else
     \ifnum\cvlanguagecountmacro<2 %
       \profilesection{LANGUAGE}%
     \else
       \profilesection{LANGUAGES}%
     \fi
  \fi
}%
\newcommand\cvlanguagecountmacro{0}%
\newcommand\advancecvlanguagecountmacro{%
  \xdef\cvlanguagecountmacro{%
     \number\numexpr\cvlanguagecountmacro+1\relax
  }%
}%
\newcommand\languageline[2]{%
  \par\noindent#1\\\grade{#2}\par%
}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cvlanguages}[2]{%
  \protected@write{\@mainaux}{}{%
    \string\advancecvlanguagecountmacro
  }%
  \addtocontents{cvl}{\string\languageline{#1}{#2}}%
}%
\newcommand\listofcvlanguages{%
  \cvlanguagesectionheading 
  \@starttoc{cvl}%
}%
\makeatother



\begin{document}

Some text.

\listofcvlanguages

\cvlanguages{Portugese}{5}
\cvlanguages{English}{5}
\cvlanguages{WeirdSpeech}{2}
\cvlanguages{OddTongue}{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]